# Unable to connect Azure SQL DB in Spark YARN Cluster using Java using azure-activedirectory-library-for-java library

Tags: java, apache-spark, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory, adal

In one of our project, we are using Azure SQL DB, authentication mode is Access Token based. We are using Spark Java to connect. We are able to connect to DB when we run our spark job as standalone but when we are running in YARN mode, we are not able to connect.
We are using the library “azure-activedirectory-library-for-java”

We are getting the error as: Login failed for user: ‘’. ClientConnectionId:

Exception:
INFO Client:
         client token: N/A
         diagnostics: User class threw exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:2b288e9e-15cc-448a-8210-0d184d27a12b
         ApplicationMaster host: 172.25.3.7
         ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
         queue: default
         start time: 1538583454649
         final status: FAILED
         tracking URL:

References:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-spark-connector

Thanks in advance.

Thanks & Regards,

-Venkat

Below is the exception stacktrace:

18/10/08 10:07:16 WARN SparkSession$Builder: Using an existing SparkSession; some configuration may not take effect.
18/10/08 10:07:16 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:8ecbc2ae-cede-4b1d-8eba-f362010f71e6
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:8ecbc2ae-cede-4b1d-8eba-f362010f71e6
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:251)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:81)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:3077)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2360)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:43)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2346)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:6276)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1793)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1404)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1068)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:904)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:451)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1014)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.(JDBCRelation.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:309)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:193)
    at com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect.DataFrameReaderFunctions.sqlDB(DataFrameReaderFunctions.scala:44)
    at com.sew.data.SQLDBConnectionEngine$.main(SQLDBConnectionEngine.scala:71)
    at com.sew.data.SQLDBConnectionEngine.main(SQLDBConnectionEngine.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:646)
18/10/08 10:07:16 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:8ecbc2ae-cede-4b1d-8eba-f362010f71e6)
18/10/08 10:07:16 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
18/10/08 10:07:16 INFO AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@683861d4{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:0}

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `Login failed for user ''.` and I don't see a user name that the login is attempting to use?

18/10/08 10:07:16 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: **Login failed for user ''.** ClientConnectionId:8ecbc2ae-cede-4b1d-8eba-f362010f71e6 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: **Login failed for user ''.** ClientConnectionId:8ecbc2ae-cede-4b1d-8eba-f362010f71e6 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError

What user are you attempting to connect as? Has this identify been added as a 'contained database user' per the instructions for creating Azure Active Directory:

[Create and populate an Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#create-and-populate-an-azure-ad)

If the above set of steps have been complete properly, you then move on to:

[Connecting using Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-spark-connector#connecting-using-access-token)

**Setup Requirement**

If you are using the access token-based authentication mode, you need to download [azure-activedirectory-library-for-java](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java) and its dependencies, and include them in the Java build path.

See [Use Azure Active Directory Authentication for authentication with SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication) to learn how to get access token to your Azure SQL database.